# What do chip-select bits represent and how do they affect overall memory addresses?

Tags: assembly, binary, memory-address

I'm currently reading Adam Osborne's introduction to microcomputers volume 1 and am having trouble understanding chip-select bits. What does each bit represent and how does the number of chips affect the number of chip-select bits needed in an address? Does requiring more chip-select bits reduce the storage capacity of a computer?

Comment: My recommendation would be to find a more recent book.

Comment: I'm reading this book to understand another book on z80 assembly. I want to learn z80 assembly to make x86 assembly learning more understandable.

Comment: starting with the older sram type memories is best before moving forward.

Comment: the classic chip select, read/write strobe address/data lines is VERY much in use today (your processors being used to read this have countless numbers of these inside)

Answer (score 0):

Z80 has IN and OUT instructions that indicate the transfer is from or to an I/O device rather than memory. For I/O devices, usually only the lower 8 bits are used, which translates into 256 possible I/O addresses (which are separate from memory read/write addresses).

The memory interface for a Z80 chip may map some of the memory address bits to the chip select bits of specific memory chips, depending on the size of the memory chips.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by depending on the size of the memory chips? I want to know how it does this. If the chip is 1024 x 4, what would the chip select bits look like?

Comment: @John - for 64KB of RAM using 1024x4 chips, 64 pairs of memory chips are needed. Each pair read/writes 8 bits, and 6 bits of the 16 memory address bits would go through a demultiplexer to select one of the 64 pairs of memory chips. Typically the upper 6 bits of the 16 bit memory address would go through the multiplexer. The remaining 10 bits of the 16 bit memory address would be connected to the address lines of the memory chips.

Comment: I was under the impression that the remaining address bits represent the microprocessor's word size. In a system with a 16-bit word size and this many chips, would a 22-bit address be needed?

Comment: @John - the Z80 has 16 address pins and 8 data pins. They would be connected to separate buses.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that there are some designs where you may want to not have the memory answer for every transaction.

One situation is that you may have a memory with say 8 bits of address, that doesn't limit you to 256 addressable items if you can put more of these chips on the board.  Put two chips on the board wire the lower 8 address bits up to both, the data lines up to both, but a small bit of logic (a simple inverter really) can be used to have address bit 8 either enable chip select on one of the chips or the other.  and address bits 7..0 then select which item within that memory.  Address bit 8 being a 0 would enable chip select on one of the memories but not the other and address bit 8 being a 1 during the transaction would assert chip select on the other memory but not the first.

Another situation is think about a 32 bit wide bus using 8 bit wide parts.  If you want to do a 32 bit write then you want to assert chip select on all the memories.  the address lines are tied to all of them in the same way but byte lane 0 bits 0-7 are on one memory, byte lane 1 bits 8-15 are on another memory and so on.  Now if the transaction on the bus tells you this is an 8 bit transaction and it is on byte lane 0 then you only assert chip select on byte lane 0 for that transaction.  16 bit lower byte lanes then only chips selects for the lower two memories are asserted the other two are not.  Only those two memories will get written the others not.  Usually there is an indicator on a wider bus (say 32 bit) that can do byte sized writes, one common way is a byte lane mask of some sort, four separate control signals which are asserted if the byte lane is used and not if not used for that transaction you can directly or through an inverter tie those to the chip select of the memory.

Chip select is simply an enable.  All the other signals are ignored if chip select is not asserted, so you can see there are various ways this can be used.  For some designs though you just tie chip select to ground (if it is asserted low) and then it always pays attention to the other signals.

Number of chip selects doesn't matter.  You could have 32 bit wide memories with a single chip select for that memory you could have a gigabit part (memories are usually spec'ed in bits not bytes the width is a separate part of that spec) or a 4 gigabit part 32 bits wide one has 4 times the memory.  They can have 8 bit wide parts with more memory than a 32 bit wide part.  There is usually one chip select per part/module but sometimes that varies too.  There is no direct connection between number of chip selects and how much or how wide the memory is, at least in this day and age, in the day of the z80 and 8088 and such you didn't have a large selection of 16 bit or wider parts, thus the entire point of the 8088 was to have their 16 bit processor be able to use the 8 bit wide parts commonly available.

Comment: I still don't understand what the address would actually be in any of these scenarios. If an 8-bit microprocessor has two RAM chips, would it have a 9-bit address(000000000)? Eight bits because it's an 8-bit processor, plus another for one or the other chip? From what i've read, that doesn't make sense. It seems like the number of bits used for the chip-select part of the address is dependent on the size of the chips. Is there no rhyme or reason to how addresses are written?

Comment: 8 bit processor does not necessarily mean 256 bytes of memory as you know from looking at the z80 stuff you have been reading.  but lets say that is true 8 bits of address, 8 bit memories, yes using two parts means you get 9 bits of address, twice as much memory (two parts) so need an additional address bit.  four parts, two more address bits 10 total and so on.

Comment: I haven't read anything on the z80 yet. The book I want to read said at the very start that I need to read Osborne's book first.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The address doesn't hold every single location or bit a microprocessor has access to if it's split between RAM chips. A microcomputer will only have as much memory as its RAM chips will allow. The word address refers only to individual "locations" in any one chip. It doesn't not represent the microprocessor's word size. The chip-select bits refer only to the particular chip. Together the address describes the chip and the location within that chip. It doesn't give information on it's own as to how much memory the computer has as every location size depends on the chips used. A chip including 256 locations doesn't mean 256 bits are stored on that chip.